# Is it possible to "hide a view" in the Navigation Controller?

Tags: ios, multithreading, asynchronous

I have an asynchronous task which is running in a particular view in the navigation controller, but when the user hit the back button, my view is removed from the navigation controller and so my asynchronous task can't be handled by my ancient view.

Is there a way to let this view in the memory when the user hit the back button ?

Comment: Do you need to render UI or yo need to do some operations like db update?

Comment: The operation that I have to do is send data to the cloud (Google Drive ; Dropbox)

Comment: Then you can create a delegate or call back property in your asynchronous to AppDelegate or any other singleton object other than the view controller, and you can send data from there. Delegate object must not be a view controller it can be anything inherited from `NSObject`

Comment: Oh ! I didn't think about it ! It's exactly what I need ! Thanks !

Comment: Glad to hear I could help you :)